# SharpDX Y position inverted

Tags: directx, directx11, sharpdx, direct2d

I am currently drawing objects and it works perfectly, when i make x bigger the objects go right and when i make x lower they go left perfect, but when i make y bigger the object goes down and when i make y lower it goes up, i am having problems discovering the part of the code that is making y inverted.

This is the code that i use to initialize:

```
    static public BitmapManager bitmapManager;
    static public Maze CurrentScene;
    static public Sound.Sound Sound;
    static public InputManager Input;
    static public Renderer renderer;
    static public Point WindowPosition;
    static public Size WindowSize;
    static public GameTime gameTime;
    static public float DeltaTime;
    static public Hierarchy hierarchy;

    static internal RenderForm form;

    static private Device device;
    static private SwapChain swapChain;
    static private Stopwatch stopwatch;
    static private Thread UpdateThread;

    static public void Initialize(Size size)
    {
        GC.Collect();

        form = new RenderForm();
        form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        form.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height);
        form.MaximizeBox = false;
        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        form.FormClosed += form_FormClosed;

        SwapChainDescription SCDescription = new SwapChainDescription()
        {
            BufferCount = 1,
            ModeDescription = new ModeDescription(form.ClientSize.Width, form.ClientSize.Height, new Rational(60, 1), Format.R8G8B8A8_UNorm),
            IsWindowed = true,
            OutputHandle = form.Handle,
            SampleDescription = new SampleDescription(1, 0),
            SwapEffect = SwapEffect.Discard,
            Usage = Usage.RenderTargetOutput
        };

        Device.CreateWithSwapChain(DriverType.Hardware, DeviceCreationFlags.BgraSupport, SCDescription, out device, out swapChain);

        Factory2D d2dFactory = new Factory2D();

        Factory factory = swapChain.GetParent<Factory>();
        factory.MakeWindowAssociation(form.Handle, WindowAssociationFlags.IgnoreAll);

        Texture2D backBuffer = Texture2D.FromSwapChain<SharpDX.Direct3D11.Texture2D>(swapChain, 0);
        RenderTargetView RenderView = new RenderTargetView(device, backBuffer);

        Surface surface = backBuffer.QueryInterface<Surface>();

        RenderTarget RenderTarget2D = new RenderTarget(d2dFactory, surface, 
                                                       new RenderTargetProperties(new PixelFormat(Format.Unknown, AlphaMode.Premultiplied)));

        form.SizeChanged += Form_SizeChanged;
        form.GotFocus += Form_GetFocus;
        form.LostFocus += Form_LostFocus;
        form.Move += Form_Move;

        WindowPosition = new Point(form.Location.X + SystemInformation.FixedFrameBorderSize.Width + SystemInformation.DragSize.Width,
                                   form.Location.Y + SystemInformation.FixedFrameBorderSize.Height + SystemInformation.CaptionHeight + SystemInformation.DragSize.Height);

        WindowSize = size;
        renderer = new Renderer(RenderTarget2D);
        Input = new InputManager();
        Sound = new Sound.Sound();
        bitmapManager = new BitmapManager(RenderTarget2D);

        hierarchy = new Hierarchy();

        gameTime = new GameTime();
        stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
    }
```

and this is the code i use to render:

```
RawMatrix3x2 CurrentTransform = renderTarget.Transform;
Sprite NewSprite = Component as Sprite;
Bitmap Texture = Game.bitmapManager.GetTexture(NewSprite.texture.TexturePath);
RawRectangleF PositionRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(NewSprite.texture.TextureSize * Zoom)).ToRawRectangleF();
float Transparency = NewSprite.Transparency;
RawRectangleF ImageRectangle = new Rectangle(new Point(0, 0), new Size(NewSprite.texture.TextureSize * Zoom)).ToRawRectangleF();
Vector2 NewScale = (Vector2)Gameobject.transform.Scale;
Matrix3x2 Translation = Matrix3x2.Translation((Vector2)Gameobject.transform.Position);
Matrix3x2 Rotation = Matrix3x2.Rotation(Gameobject.transform.Rotation.X);
Matrix3x2 Scale = Matrix3x2.Scaling((Vector2)Gameobject.transform.Scale);
renderTarget.Transform = (Translation * Rotation * Scale).ToRawMatrix3x2();
renderTarget.DrawBitmap(Texture, PositionRectangle, Transparency, BitmapInterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor, ImageRectangle);
renderTarget.Transform = CurrentTransform;
```

If you need anything else please warn me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't done anything wrong, the direct2d coordinate space origin is in the upper left and the y axis increases downward.  From the [direct2d documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756655(v=vs.85).aspx#the_direct2d_coordinate_space):

> Direct2D uses a left-handed coordinate space; that is, positive x-axis
>   values increase to the right and positive y-axis values increase
>   downward. Everything on the screen is positioned relative to the
>   origin, which is the point where the x-axis and y-axis intersect (0,
>   0), as shown in the following illustration. Direct2D render targets
>   use this coordinate space.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i will accept, but if you know how i can make when y-axis increased go upward i would appreciate.

Comment: @Maze Sorry but I'm not aware of a way to do this; all I came across was [this forum discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/25ef2bee-3edc-44be-b664-4a34c392be09/d2d1-y-axis-reverse?forum=windowsdirectshowdevelopment) where a negative scaling matrix is suggested but it seems to be implied in the last post that this isn't allowed.